# Django's rfile alternative in DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I want to use `rfile.read()` in Django rest framework's `APIView` class. However, I could not find any alternative to this function.

Comment: What is `rfile.read()`? `file.read()`??

Comment: @dudulu https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.rfile